# Why does rails generate add timestamps to models by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I would expect that most models do not require information about when they were created and updated as a necessary feature of the model. Indeed, the [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) doesn't use or mention them. So what is the reasoning behind creating created_at/updated_at fields for models by default?

Comment: Search `timestamp` in that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may disable them from being created in your migrations if you would like.  But to answer your question, you may be surprised how many models tend to have some sort of need to use data from the time stamps in some way, whether thats setting the default scope of that table, using the data to expire certain things, etc...  They are included by default because they are useful and convenient to a lot of people, but if you are positive you don't need those feilds, feel free to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp is added to make it easier for user. A timestamp can be used to understand when what model was created and also to distinguish between different databases